# What am I doing wrong: Structure cannot be indexed because it has no default property (WITH CLAUSE)

Tags: vb.net

Am getting: "Structure cannot be indexed because it has no default property". What am I doing wrong?

```
With grid.Rows(10).Cells
    Dim note As New Note With {.ID = "Blah", _
                               .Date = "1/1/2011", _
                               .Message = "AAA", _
                               .Type = "ABC", _
                               .SubType = "DEF", _
                               .ReferenceKey = !SetRefNum.Value}
End With
```

And Note looks like:

```
Public Structure Note
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property [Date] As Date
    Public Property Message As String

    Public Property Type As String
    Public Property SubType As String
    Public Property ReferenceKey As String
 End Structure
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with `!SetRefNum.Value`.  You use the `!` operator to reference an index in a collection, usually a dictionary.  The `Note` class requires a `Default` property to use this terminology.

```
Class Note
    Public ReadOnly Default Property Item(Key As String) As String
        Get
            Return Settings(Key)
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Settings As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

So the term `!SetRefNum.Value` will translate to `note.Item("SetRefNum.Value")`.

I'm going to take a guess you're after something completely different.

See the **Member Access Operators** section of the page [Special Characters in Code (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxda45fy.aspx) for more information.

**Edit:** Ammended answer for ammended question.

I suggest the following approach:

```
With grid.Rows(10).Cells
    Dim ReferenceKey As String = !SetRefNum.Value
    Dim note As New Note With {.ID = "Blah", _
                               .Date = "1/1/2011", _
                               .Message = "AAA", _
                               .Type = "ABC", _
                               .SubType = "DEF", _
                               .ReferenceKey = ReferenceKey}
End With
```

Somehow, I doubt that will work either.  You might need something like:

```
With grid.Rows(10).Cells
    Dim ReferenceKey As String = .Item(SetRefNum.Value)
```

Comment: I left out a part of the code that I had... You're right this was in a "WITH" block. I changed the original post.

Comment: The trouble is you have two `With` blocks there: `With grid.Rows(10).Cells` and `With note`.  See edited answer for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The `!` character is used in C#. For VB, you'll want to use the `Not` keyword. So, it should look like this:

```
Dim note As New Note With {.ID = "Blah", _
                           .Date = "1/1/2011", _
                           .Message = "AAA", _
                           .Type = "ABC", _
                           .SubType = "DEF", _
                           .ReferenceKey = Not SetRefNum.Value}
```

Also, assuming you're using Visual Studio 2010 because of the auto properties in your Structure, you don't need the trailing underscores. I would write it like this:

```
Dim note = New Note With {.ID = "Blah", 
                          .Date = "1/1/2011", 
                          .Message = "AAA", 
                          .Type = "ABC", 
                          .SubType = "DEF", 
                          .ReferenceKey = Not SetRefNum.Value}
```

**Edit:** Well, your ReferenceKey field is a String, so I'm not sure you were going for the boolean value. Maybe @Hand-E-Food was closer to the right answer.